# CSS - How to insure that a input will be in the middle of a specific area

Tags: html, css

I'm having a simple row with three utf-8 arrows

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">&#9660;</div>
  <div id="two">&#9650;</div>
  <div id="three">&#9660;</div>
</div>
```

So what I am trying to do is to have the arrows in the same row, but I want them to be in the middle of their height and their width - no matter what text size value they will get.

I've tried the next CSS code -

```
#container{
display: inline-block;
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
}


#one{
float:left;
width: 20%;
font-size: 90px;
}

#two{
float:left;
width: 20%;
font-size: 50px;
}

#three{
float:left;
width: 20%;
font-size: 60px;

}
```

As you can understand it sure don't work, any ideas what can I do?
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Check this: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ - helpful article on vertical aligning.. horizontal aligning is a simple case of adding "text-align: center"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some styles to the 3 elements:

```
#container{
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
display: table;
}
#one{
width: 20%;
font-size: 90px;
}

#two{
width: 20%;
font-size: 50px;
}

#three{
width: 20%;
font-size: 60px;
}
#one,#two,#three{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gootoud6/1/)**

Comment: Well as you can see in your example the large arrow makes the two other to be in the top but I that when ever there is a large arrow than the other small ones will be in the middle vertically

Comment: @PESfcs i think you're looking at the wrong fiddle here.. the arrows are all in the middle.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to display elements as `inline-block` and set `vertical-align: middle`, `text-align: center`.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
#one,
#two,
#three {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#one {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 90px;
}
#two {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 50px;
}
#three {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">&#9660;</div>
  <div id="two">&#9650;</div>
  <div id="three">&#9660;</div>
</div>
```